# Picasso "Resize and centerCrop" or ImageView "centerCrop"?

Tags: android, gridview, optimization, imageview, picasso

I am currently optimizing my Android app, and was wondering whether it's faster to resize and center crop an image using Picasso, or to just load the image straight into an ImageView which has a set layout_width and layout_height, and a scaleType attribute that is "centerCrop".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just load the image straight into an ImageView and use scaleType attribute "centerCrop" in the layout without the intervention of Picasso, because in low specs devices you could see a little lag between the conversion of scaleType. If you have a placeholder assigned to the ImageView, that could be a problem.

Comment: I haven't had time to run on benchmarks on either version so I suppose that's my next course of action. 

Out of curiosity, do you know what kind of calculations Picasso would have to make versus inserting into an ImageView and letting Android take care of the resizing/center crop?

Comment: You can check the source code here: [Picasso in github](https://github.com/square/picasso). If you check the BitmapHunter.java file, you'll see how it calculates the ratios of width and height to assign them to the new bitmap... It's kind of complicated. I would need to check the android algorithm to say if Picasso or Android is better... but at this point I think Android is better because of the little lag that I've seem in low specs devices using Picasso centerCrop.

Comment: Gracias, mate. Will check on that and refactor my code if need be.